# VSCode Terminal - Changing current working directory's color

Tags: visual-studio-code

title basically says it all.

Currently, the working directory displayed in the terminal (e.g. `PS C:\Users\User\Python\Projects>`) is colored white, but I'd like to assign a different color. The new color should be exclusive only for that path, and not affect the entirety of the terminals fontcolor, so just changig `terminal.foreground` in the `workbench.colorCustomizations` ain't gonna cut it.

If it's possible to change that, please help me, otherwise inform me of the impossibility of the task at hand, so that I can stop wasting my time in the google search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Open Powershell and type the follwoing and press Enter

```
New-Item -Type File -Path $PROFILE -Force
```

Go to Documents > WindowsPowerShell folder and open file called Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 with Notepad.

Copy the following command and paste it in the file

```
function prompt {
    $color = 'Magenta'
    Write-Host ("" + $(Get-Location) +">") -NoNewLine `
     -ForegroundColor $Color
    return " "
}
```

You can change Magenta with Red, Yellow, Cyan, etc...

Save the file and then Run PowerShell as Administrator and type, run the following in order:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy

RemoteSigned

yes
```

In case you changed your mind and want to restore default options, just open PowerShell as Administrator and type,run the following in order

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy

Restricted

yes
```

and then Remove the PowerShell Folder in Documents

I have also created a Video to customize the path of Powershell, it contains similar steps in case you want step by step
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlOzVvY9R-g

Comment: This does not change the color, any color really, but instead for some reason moves the "PS" from infront of the directory to after it and in a new line. Something seems to have gone wrong, do you know what? And while I am at it, what does the "PS" stand for?

Comment: @Solo "PS" is shortcut for Powershell, as for the problem please be aware that " Write-Host ("" + $(Get-Location) +">") -NoNewLine ` " is one line. I have updated the code you can try it now once again

Comment: Great, this works! One more thing tho, how can I pass a custom color? Judging from Microsofts documentation, that does not seem to be possible. But that can't be, can it?

Comment: @Solo You can change Magenta with Red, Yellow, Cyan, etc...